# How can I add heading on the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add columns to the dataframe `xFlattened` ? In my case `xFlattened.columns` didn`t help me.

```py
def corrFilter(x, bound):
    xCorr = x.corr()
    xFiltered = xCorr[((xCorr >= bound) | (xCorr <= -bound)) & (xCorr !=1.000)]
    xFlattened = xFiltered.unstack().sort_values(ascending = False).drop_duplicates()
    xFlattened.columns = ["first_value", "second_value", "corr"]
    return xFlattened

d = {'review_scores_accuracy': [1.1, 2.0, 4.5, 5.0, 4.9, 4.8, 4.7], 
     'review_scores_rating': [1.1, 2.0, 4.6, 3.9, 4.2, 4.5, 4.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = corrFilter(df, .7)
df
```

What I want

```py
             first_value              second_value      percentage
0 review_scores_accuracy      review_scores_rating        0.968217
1                           review_scores_accuracy             NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `reset_index` in your function to convert the Series to DataFrame:

```
xFlattened = xFiltered.unstack().sort_values(ascending = False).drop_duplicates().reset_index()
```

output:

```
              first_value            second_value      corr
0  review_scores_accuracy    review_scores_rating  0.968217
1  review_scores_accuracy  review_scores_accuracy       NaN
```

Comment: In line 1 there's an additional entry in the first column now which wasn't there before

Comment: @ThomasWeller it was there, just hidden as this was an index ;)

Comment: Ok, yes. I can see it in the debugger in the original version as well.